# IIRF Redirection Issue in SiteCore

Tags: sitecore, iirf

We are trying to handle redirects using IIRF in SiteCore WebApplication. Here we note that the redirections happen as expected in the Classic Mode of the Application Pool but the same does not happen when using Integrated Mode for the Application Pool.

We need the same to work in the Integrated Mode.

Any Inputs on the same will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I register **IIRF 64bit** version for a website using **.NET 4** in **integrated mode**:

```
%appcmd% set config "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd" /section:isapiFilters /"+[name='IIRF',path='%iirfdll%',enabled='true',enableCache='false',preCondition='bitness64']" /commit:apphost
```

You'll have to execute this from within an *elevated command prompt*, and replace the variables:

- `%appcmd%` : `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd`
- `%sitename%` : Name of the site in IIS
- `%iirfdll%` : Path to the dll (app pool user must have access)

Haven't had any problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Ionic Isapi Rewrite before and it worked for 95% of the cases I needed it for, But eventually I moved over to use the standard Url Rewrite Module for IIS7 that can be installed and configured through the IIS Manager. I found it a much more user friendly module.
See the [website here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)